# Strongly typing json data returned by WebAPI

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a Webapp and a WPF app that will reference a WebAPI using entity framework. In order to share data structures between the two I have been leaning towards using a DTO. The DTO will be defined in a seperate library that both projects will reference.

[image]

**WebAPI** -Each API action will consume or return a DTO which then will be translated to/from a Entity to be stored into the database.ex. Person Entity with ID,FirstName,LastName
will be converted to PersonDTO with ID,Name.

**Webapp and WPF app** - will call the webapi and serialize the data to a DTO. They will not reference Entities.ex PersonDTO and not the Person Entity.

My question is if this is the correct approach and design? 
Is there any more seperation needed? should I move the entity framework to a seperate project?

Comment: Yes, that sounds good.

Comment: Its a perfectly good model, however I would think carefully about what value the DTOs are adding and if it's worth all the mapping back and forth between your entities.  One reason I usually do this is that I want to return a much simpler DTO than the EF entity it maps to.

Comment: @BenRobinson That is exactly my reason as well.ex my entities have Firstname  and Last name as seperate columns. but mostly places in UI it will be referred to as name.rather that have to do that concatenation at every consuming end,I thought DTO would serve a good purpose. This is a very minimalist example. another could be some information derived from a relationship ex. Count of course a person has.

Comment: @superartsy Then your model sounds like how I would approach the problem.